# R version Machine Learning Server SQL Server 2019

Tags: r, sql-server

Using Machine Learning Server and SQL Server 2017. Unfortunately, it only supports R 3.3.3. I googled a lot but could not find a definitive answer. Which version of R is supported whilst using Machine Learning Server on SQL Server 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What is SQL Server Machine Learning Services with Python and R?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver15) states:

> ### Python and R versions
>
> The following lists the versions of Python and R that are included in Machine Learning Services.
>
> | SQL Server version | Python version | R version |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | SQL Server 2017 | 3.5.2 | 3.3.3 |
> | SQL Server 2019 | 3.7.3 | 3.5.2 |

So 2019 installs 3.5.2 for R, while 2017 (contrary to your question) installs 3.3.3.

Comment: OK thanks. I am sorry I did not find this only the 2017 bit.

Answer (score 3):

The versions of R and Python installed is only a default.  You can update it.

Update to SQL 2017 CU22 or later, and you can change the version of R used:

> If you have installed one of the above Cumulative Updates for SQL
> Server 2016 or 2017, you may have multiple versions of R in a SQL
> instance. Each version is contained in a subfolder of the instance
> folder with the name R_SERVICES.. (the folder from the
> original installation may not have a version number appended to the
> folder name).

[Change R Runtime Version - SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/change-default-language-runtime-version?view=sql-server-2017#change-r-runtime-version)

The process for SQL Server 2019 is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/custom-runtime-r?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: thanks. however, i think it is not that straightforward, especially if one wants to use the revoscale r